# Getting error with `offlineimap` on first run:

Tags: email, mutt, runtime-error

I've been getting kinda tired of Gmail's UI and email clients are too bloated or just feel wrong. So I've been trying out Mutt and it looks like it'll be the thing I'll be using.

I've been following this guide by Steve Losh on how to setup Mutt (or rather, how he did it): http://stevelosh.com/blog/2012/10/the-homely-mutt/#getting-email

However I've run across a problem, I'm at the point where he tells you to run `offlineimap` for the first time. However I immediately run across this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/offlineimap", line 23, in <module>
    oi.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/init.py", line 44, in run
    options, args = self.parse_cmd_options()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/init.py", line 173, in parse_cmd_options
    config.read(configfilename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 546, in _read
    raise e
ConfigParser.ParsingError: File contains parsing errors: /Users/eduan/.offlineimaprc
    [line 21]: '}.get(folder, folder)\n'
    [line 34]: '}.get(folder, folder)\n'
```

And I have *no* idea what it means. I've followed Steve Losh's instructions as closely as I could so the config files should be OK, including the Python script he provides.

Any help is very appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! For some reason having a new line before that statement messed it up... Oh I know... Python is indent based I forgot...